# Parsing very large xml lazily

Tags: scala, xml-parsing

I have a huge xml file (40 gbs). I would like to extract some fields from it without loading the entire file into memory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at scala's XMLEventReader

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A quick example with XMLEventReader based on a tutorial for SAXParser [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) (as posted by Rinat Tainov).

I'm sure it can be done better but just to show basic usage:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.xml.pull._

object Main extends App {
  val xml = new XMLEventReader(Source.fromFile("test.xml"))

  def printText(text: String, currNode: List[String]) {
    currNode match {
      case List("firstname", "staff", "company") => println("First Name: " + text)
      case List("lastname", "staff", "company") => println("Last Name: " + text)
      case List("nickname", "staff", "company") => println("Nick Name: " + text)
      case List("salary", "staff", "company") => println("Salary: " + text)
      case _ => ()
    }
  }

  def parse(xml: XMLEventReader) {
    def loop(currNode: List[String]) {
      if (xml.hasNext) {
        xml.next match {
          case EvElemStart(_, label, _, _) =>
            println("Start element: " + label)
            loop(label :: currNode)
          case EvElemEnd(_, label) =>
            println("End element: " + label)
            loop(currNode.tail)
          case EvText(text) =>
            printText(text, currNode)
            loop(currNode)
          case _ => loop(currNode)
        }
      }
    }
    loop(List.empty)
  }

  parse(xml)
}
```

Comment: what if XMLEventReader gets the xml from a url with a connection? then connection to that url times out before the lazy evaluation gets done. Any ideas on that issue?

Comment: A URLConnection will not time out while data is being transmitted. Otherwise no long-lasting download would be possible ;) ... A connection times out if no packets are received for a set time-period.

Comment: Can you pls help me with what 'loop' is doing. from what I understand its looping over tags, but I am not sure. Looking for any documentation that has a mention of it but can't find any. I understand that this is a old post but can somebody help? Even a link would be helpful. Meanwhile I am also looking

Comment: @Vikash It is more like events which are generated when some XML element is encountered. Look at the documentation for available event types (under "Known Subclasses"): http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala-xml/scala/xml/pull/XMLEvent.html

Comment: @Arjan Thank you. I wasn't aware of tail recursion then since I was just starting in scala. This looks more like it if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

User [SAXParser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html), it will not load entire xml to memory. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) good java example, easily can be used in scala.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy looking at alternative xml libraries then [Scales Xml](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml) provides three main pull parsing approaches:

1. [Iterator based](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.4.3/PullParsing.html#Pull_Model) - simply use hasNext, next to get more items
2. [iterate function](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.4.3/PullParsing.html#Simple_Reading_Of_Repeated_Sections) - provides an Iterator but for trees identified by a simple path
3. [Iteratee based](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.4.3/RepeatedSections.html#Pull_Parsing_ResumableIter.27atees) - allows combinations of multiple paths

The focus of the upcoming 0.5 version is asynchronous parsing via aalto-xml, allowing for additional non-blocking control options.

In all cases you can control both memory usage and how the document is processed with Scales.