# Reading gzipped XML in scala

Tags: xml, scala

As I attempted to read a xml.gz file into Scala, I received the following error:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:701)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:567)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1896)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1761)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1799)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:156)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader$class.loadXML(XMLLoader.scala:41)
at scala.xml.XML$.loadXML(XML.scala:60)
at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader$class.loadFile(XMLLoader.scala:50)
at scala.xml.X
```

I have the following code:

```
import scala.xml.XML 
val xml = XML.loadFile("/home/vagrant/miniprojects/spark/allVotes/part-00380.xml.gz")
```

I have more than 2,000 xml.gz files to read in. What would be an efficient solution to this? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Showing your work (how you're doing the parsing, and particularly how you're doing the gzip decompression) in the smallest possible complete and testable form would be a place to start. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...so, you *aren't* doing gzip decompression at all, then. How is it a surprise that you can't read a gzip file as if it were an XML file?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. As I gunzip the file, it takes up too much memory...

Comment: ...if you need to run queries against a combined set of XML documents that require more RAM than you have available to store, consider using an XQuery database for the purpose. (Disregard if when you said "memory" you actually meant on-disk storage). Chances are if you can't store the decompressed text in RAM, you don't have enough memory for a DOM built from that text either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.xml.gz` is not XML at the outer layer -- it's gzip. Use a GZIPInputStream to decompress this as it's being read:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
import scala.xml.XML

def loadXmlGz(filename : String) = {
  XML.load(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(new java.io.File(filename))))
}

var xml = loadXmlGz("/home/vagrant/miniprojects/spark/allVotes/part-00380.xml.gz")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you, but I am pretty naive about this. As I used this code, I still receive memory error by only importing one .xml.gz file. `scala> var xml = loadXmlGz("/home/vagrant/miniprojects/spark/allVotes/part-00000.xml.gz")
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: If you don't have enough memory to store a DOM structure for your XML documents, you'll need to either give your JVM more memory -- or rewrite your code to not use a DOM-based model. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184212/parsing-very-large-xml-lazily for an example on how that might be done.

Comment: Out of the box, btw, when I run `scala-2.11` at a command line, I get it running in a JVM with a 256MB heap limit. That's not a huge amount of headroom; if you aren't setting custom `JAVA_OPTS`, you probably should.

Comment: ...beyond that, though, memory-limit issues should probably be in a different question.