# How do you continuously read a file in scala?

Tags: scala

I will get the stream of XML files and saved in file(xxxxname).The file will be continuously growing.I want to read the file line by line in continuous flow .Here's basically what I'm doing now:

```
for(line <- Source.fromFile("/home/ubuntu/sample.xml").getLines())      
   println(line)
```

Can anyone help me how to read file continuously in scala?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a SAX Parser if you don't want to load entire files into memory. There is a good answer on that here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13193706/2115809

Comment: Thanks haggy. Already i wrote code to parse the XML file .I want the code to read the files continuous in scala.

Comment: Meaning you want to retrieve all files in a directory and parse them using your existing XML parsing lib?

Comment: i m getting XML file   and saved into one file say sample.txt or sample.txt...I will be  getting data continuously ..So i need to read every lines ..